# biblatex-dw first name first in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

How to reverse the order of Name, Firstname in the bibliography when using a *-dw style ?  The [xpatch trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145443/35898) does only work with built-in and some other styles, not biblatex-dw ones.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles
Not sure if this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method that works for the `biblatex-dw` styles as well as for the standard styles that come with `biblatex` is to declare

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
```

in the preamble. See the section "Bibliography – order of first names and last names" of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/510) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, Adam},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: newer versions of `biblatex` should use `family-given` instead of `first-last` would you mind editing your question to that effect?