# How to reverse name and first name?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

With biblatex and verbose-trad2 style, I would like to reverse the order of the last name and the first name **for inline references.**

The default behavior is:

> John DOE, Title, place : publisher, year

for inline references (in my case, in a footnote with `footcite` command) and:

> DOE, John, Title, place : publisher, year

in the bibliography at the end of the document.

I would like to have both inline and final references in the following format (similar to the bibiography style).

> DOE, John, Title, place : publisher, year

P-S : There are some close questions (like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146137/biblatex-dw-first-name-first-in-bibliography)) but only about the final bibliography (and no inline references). `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` works only for the ending references (not inline ones).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will also have to set `default`, as the cite commands in `verbose-trad2`* temporarily set `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` (and by ... default `default` is `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}`).

So just issue

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

in the preamble. Note that `default` is used in a few other places as well, so this change also affects the bibliography. If you want a modification that affects only the citations, see below.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\begin{document}
  A\footcite{wilde}
  B\footcite{cicero}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

---

* The code can be found in `verbose-trad2.cbx`, the sixth line below is the offending one.

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

This shows us that a different solution would be

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

But of course that's longer. The effect is slightly different as this will only affect the name format in long citations and not anywhere else.

---

*edit* See the edit history for the pre-3.3 code if you are using an outdated version of `biblatex`. Cf. [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).