# making citations bold latex

Tags: biblatex, citing

Simple problem I am having I apologise for the simplicity but my google skills seem to be lacking and I cannot find an answer speedily.I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and have a successful bibliography without issue and make citations using:

```
\cite{test}
```

however my citations are appearing as:

[image: citation]

I was hoping to make the citations in the text **bold**. Also in the printed bibliography at the end of the document the full author list is being condensed as follows: 
[image: cite2]

I was hoping to display the full Author list and reverse the et al. if possible. Any help would be much appreciated and I apologise for the simplicity of the problems.

**Edit**: heres my example tex and bib files/close representation:

```
%Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{superintro}

\input{chapters/superintro}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bibliography .bib

```
@report{RFC3550,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and S. Casgner and R. Frederick and V. Jacobson},
    title = {RFC 3550, RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications},
    url = {https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550},
    year = {2003},
}

@report{RFC2326,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and A. Rao and R. Lanphier},
    title = {RFC 2326, Real Time Streaming Protocol},
    url = {https://rools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326},
    year = {1998},
}
```

within the superintro .tex file I am simply doing things such as cite{rfc2326}

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimal example? This kind of specification/modification of existing bib styles is more easily achieved with `biblatex`.

Comment: For the second part try `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` (and also `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` if that is not enough) - see [How to reverse name and first name?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151820/35864). All authors can be displayed with [`maxbibnames=999`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864). (Of course all this assumes you really use `biblatex` as suggested by the tags.)

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}` makes citation labels bold. If you want to unbold them for the bibliography, add `\AtBeginBibliography{
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mknumalph{#1}}
}`.

Comment: Did the suggestions above do what you want? If so a short heads-up would be nice, if not it would be great if you could explain what exactly did not work.

Comment: For the name problem try `maxbibnames=999` (I don't quite understand what you mean by "reverse the *et al*", you can reverse the names into a "last, first" format via `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}`).

Answer (score 5):

You can easily make the labels bold using

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}
```

If you want to un-bold them for the bibliography, you want

```
\AtBeginBibliography{
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mknumalph{#1}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite[43]{geer} ipsum.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]