# Biblatex: How to automatically make in-text citations bold with given keyword, within the alpha style?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need this simple behaviour for citations key using biblatex. I need some references (the ones having a given keyword in the .bib file) to appear with a bold citation key in the text (and possibly also in the printed bibliography).

This question is similar to what was asked in [Biblatex: How to automatically make in-text citations bold given a condition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429874/biblatex-how-to-automatically-make-in-text-citations-bold-given-a-condition) but there, the numeric citation style was used, while I need it with the alpha style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required modifications are very similar to the ones in [Biblatex: How to automatically make in-text citations bold given a condition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429874/35864), but the basis for the `cite` macro is the definition from [`alphabetic.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/bcc7970e4020533cf9cf430b222b5699c1bd92f1/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/alphabetic.cbx#L14-L21) and not from [`numeric.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/bcc7970e4020533cf9cf430b222b5699c1bd92f1/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx#L15-L22). Furthermore, we need to redefine `labelalphawidth` for the bibliography and not `labelnumberwidth`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\ifkeyword{important}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{boldimportant}{\ifkeyword{important}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printtext[boldimportant]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelalpha}%
      \printfield{extraalpha}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  booktitle = {Why We Matter},
  date      = {1980},
  keywords  = {important},
}
@book{hacker,
  author    = {James Hacker},
  title     = {The Government},
  date      = {1981},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby,hacker}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [**App80**; Hac81], "App80" is in bold.]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same, but printing two different bibliographies and *with different styles* ? Namely, the first bibliography (the one in bold, shold be numeric, and the other one should be alpha).

Comment: @Raziel That is a but trickier. In general `biblatex` does not allow you to mix two different styles in one document. But often there are acceptable workarounds. I suggest you ask a new question about this (ideally with a but of background info).

Comment: @Raziel Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299064/35864 can help you enough already.