# BibTex Author problem

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have a Problem with my BibTex Settings. When printing I want first name before surname. Right not it is the other way around.

Also, if I have multiple authors, the first one is displayed surname, first name and every following author is displayed first name surname (without comma).

I think that this is very bad styling because it should be the same for all authors. Here I have some of my configurations for you:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    bibwarn=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    style=authoryear,
    backref=true
]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
```

And my BibTex:

```
@book{Dean.2004,
    title={MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters},
    author={Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay},
    year={2004},
    url={http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html},
    publisher={Sixth Symposium on Operating System Design and Implementation}
}
```

And last how it is displayed right now

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This style is largely used: the rationale is that the first author's family name is used for browsing the list of references; for the other authors, the rule that the given name precedes the family name prevails.

Comment: Try `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}`, see [How to reverse name and first name?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151820/35864), for example. But as egreg says, this will certainly make locating a reference harder. Or did you want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the comments.
First of all I want it to follow one standard so first-last or last first. as you can see right now the first author is last-first and the second is first-last.
I'll try the command you suggested.

Comment: Hey there. I think I found an easy way to solve my Problem.
instead of
{Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay}
I just wrote
{{Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay}}
And it seems not that it is displayed just as it is written down...

Comment: Writing `{{Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay}}` is really nor a good idea it will essentially make `biblatex` think there is only one author of the work called "Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay". Please make the author field read `{Dean, Jeffrey and Ghemawat, Sanjay}` and add `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` to your preamble.

Comment: Wow that was so...my bad. I had problems with the command but i guess it was at the wrong position. It works perfectly fine now. Thanks everyone.